# Multiple directive instances and events

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I use multiple times on a page. It fires an event when the state changes, and the controller then handles the event.

The problem is that the event is fired twice. I get why this happens, but I am stuck either trying to find a workaround or better design. Any tips?

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xObOvi253qejphU5arFr

Comment: Should each directive modify the parent scope's `foo` property?  If not, simply add `scope: true` to your directive and then each one will then have its own `foo` property (and only one event will fire).

Comment: In you plunker, all the elements share the same $scope, why don't you just use $watch directly in the main controller ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define isolated scope to make the directive reusable. A simple fix is to just add `scope: {}` to create an isolated scope so when you click on each button, it only fire once.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},  // Add this line to create an isolated scope
    template: '<div>Foo: {{foo}}</div><button ng-click="incrementFoo()">Increment Foo</button>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.foo = 0;
      $scope.incrementFoo = function () {
        $scope.foo += 1;
      };

      $scope.$watch('foo', function () {
        $scope.$emit('fooChanged', {foo: $scope.foo});
        console.log($scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Ah... I missed that. Thanks! Now the problem is in creating my example I forgot that my scope is actually shared via `$location.search().foo`. I do actually want this sharing; I just thought it was the scope itself that was shared (i.e. not via $location). So I think my answer may be to refactor the controller into a service...

Comment: My refactored plunk, with state stored in service rather than the directive's controller.. http://plnkr.co/edit/wwwp3y